# how to manage multiple wifi access points without interference

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid, interference

i have a radio which can connect to multiple ssids depending on what is within range

i am struggling with wifi interference at work. i have 4 access points within close proximity. if i set the first 3 Access Points on channel 1,6 and 11, can i set the fourth one on channel 1 but with a different SSID name. the questions is will it interfere although it has a different SSID but on the same channel as the other Access point?

Comment: I'm guessing these are consumer grade AP you're using at work? If they are enterprise grade APs, they should have feature that can adjust there power level to minimize interference. Without knowing the make and model of your AP, it'll be hard for me to suggest a solution if there's one.

Comment: yes its a consumer grade(ligowave dlb 2.4ghz) i can manage the power levels myself.

Comment: What do you mean by "struggling with wifi interference"?  What is the evidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, APs on same same channel will interfere with each other in the sense that if they are close enough to each other, only one sender can use the channel. The other access point (and other stations on that channel) will detect that and be silent for that timeslice (frame). So both will work, but you'll get a reduction in air bandwidth when both are in use.

So choose the two APs that are farthest apart, and give those the same channel.

Automatic or manual power reduction reduces this kind of interference, as do multiple antennas with beamforming.

In doubt, measure: There are e.g. smartphone apps that can show you the signal strength of all the APs your phone can currently receive.

As all WLAN communication uses a number of channels (4, or even 8 for 802.11n with higher throughput), having two APs on channel 1 is still a lot better than, say, having one AP one channel 4: This AP will interfer *both* with the APs on channel 1 and channel 6.

**Edit**

If you want to understand the role of the SSID: This is just information in the regular broadcast ("beacon") sent out by the APs, and a data field in some of the management packets. It enables the WLAN client to choose the AP it wants to associate with, and it helps to sort out different "networks" (yours and your neighbour's, for example) on the protocol level, but that's about all it does.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i was thinking if its different SSID it wont, but this clarifies it for me thanks.

Comment: The distance and intervening walls / obstructions help a lot - make sure that the two APs with the least visibility of each other are the ones sharing the same channel.  You can verify by turning 3/4 off, walking around the office using a mobile app like Wifi Analyzer to see where it's weakest, and repeating for the other APs.  Modern APs can intelligently work together to constructively interfere with each other, but that's a much more complicated topic.